# Recursive Parent/Child in same table query in SQL where parent is PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, parent-child

I have seen a lot of examples about how to implement a recursive query where there is the parent and the child in the same table, but in the examples, the child has a parent and I need at the contrary, when a parent has a child.
I would like to obtain all children in recursive mode just like in the image.
[image: Expected results]

In the image, you can see, I have a parent with id 1, it has a child with id 2. The child 2 is a parent too who has a child with id 3, etc.
I don't know how to create a recursive query to obtain all the childs from a parent.
You can access to the next link to execute the sql online: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dbed2/1

Comment: This is probably the first example for recursive CTEs you'll find in a text book. Just google it and you'll find good examples.

Comment: Thanks The Impaler. I have found a lot of examples but always the child is the Primary key and a parent can has many children, in this case. I have a parent with just one child and child with one child, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the results you are asking for:

```
with cte as (
      select idchild, idparent,
             convert(varchar(max), idchild) as children
      from family f
      where not exists (select 1 from family f2 where f2.idparent = f.idchild)
      union all
      select f.idchild, f.idparent,
             concat(f.idchild, ',', cte.children)
      from cte join
           family f
           on cte.idparent = f.idchild
     )
 select *
 from cte
 order by idchild;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dbed2/6) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks so much, you're a crack!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
with
n as (
  select idparent, idchild, 1 as lvl, 
    cast(concat('', idchild) as varchar(255)) as children from family
union all
  select n.idparent, f.idchild, lvl + 1, 
    cast(concat(children, ',', f.idchild) as varchar(255))
  from n
  join family f on f.idparent = n.idchild
)
select n.idparent, f.idchild, n.children
from n
join (
  select idparent, max(lvl) as maxlvl from n group by idparent
) m on n.idparent = m.idparent and n.lvl = m.maxlvl
join family f on f.idparent = n.idparent
order by n.idparent
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dbed2/13).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SQL Server 2017 or newer you can use the following:

```
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Child.idParent,
           Parent.idChild
    FROM CTE AS Parent
        INNER JOIN dbo.Table_1 AS Child
            ON Parent.idParent = Child.idChild)
SELECT CTE.idParent,
       STRING_AGG(CTE.idChild, ', ') AS Childs
FROM CTE
GROUP BY CTE.idParent;
```

but if you have older version use the following :

```
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Child.idParent,
           Parent.idChild
    FROM CTE AS Parent
        INNER JOIN dbo.Table_1 AS Child
            ON Parent.idParent = Child.idChild)
SELECT DISTINCT
       B.idParent,
       STUFF(
       (
           SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CTE.idChild)
           FROM CTE
           WHERE B.idParent = CTE.idParent
           ORDER BY CTE.idChild
           FOR XML PATH('')
       ),
       1,
       1,
       ''
            ) AS Childs
FROM CTE AS B
```